# What should I use to stop the sleep() function in C if a condition changes in that period of time (doesn't hold anymore)?

Tags: c, windows, sleep

I'm an *amateur* in C and I have the following task: We are given a two-dimensional table with the player controlling an 'X' in the middle. The player should have the possibility to move the 'X' around. However, every 2 seconds a random character appears in a specific point near a border of the table, such that if all the boxes near the border have a character in them, the player loses.

I'm having problems with moving the 'X' around and at the same time random characters appearing every 2 seconds. If I press the button to move 'X' in any direction but the code is still *'sleeping'*, the change will happen only after the certain remaining time has passed which is nearly not good enough - **1 move per 2 seconds**.

I want the sleep() function to **stop** when there is a **keyboard input**, print the changed position on the table and **start again** with the remaining time after that or at least just sleep again for 2 seconds. However, I am unable to understand all the complex stuff like multi-threading at the moment so could you please elaborate in simplistic terms your answer? My PC is using **Windows**.

Here is a part of my code:

```
void move()
{
    if (kbhit())
    {
        chkb = getch();//character from keyboard
        if ((int)chkb == 27)//if chkb is ESC
        {
            printf("\nGame Exited. We already miss you!");
            stop();
        }
        else
        {
            changeposition();
            printTable();
        }
    }
}

while (1)
    {
        move();
        switch (rand() % 4)
        {
        case 0:
            balls[p1][p2] = 'R';//array of chars
            break;
        case 1:
            balls[p1][p2] = 'G';
            break;
        case 2:
            balls[p1][p2] = 'B';
            break;
        case 3:
            balls[p1][p2] = 'Y';
            break;
        default:
            balls[p1][p2] = '?';
        }

        printTable();
        verifyLose();
        Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
    printTable();
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
Sleep(for a time, if some condition is true);
if(condition is false){
    ->make it true
    ->start sleep again with remaining time
}
```

Or something similar to that. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't call `Sleep()`. Incorporate a call to `clock()` in the key-testing loop, and check it against a target time.

Comment: Instead of `sleep(2000)`, use eg `sleep(20)` within a `0` to `100` counter and be ready for a 100-fold increase in processor usage

Comment: @WeatherVane could you post your comment as an answer so i give you that tick thingy? Your idea is most clever and helped me a lot!

Comment: @pmg why would I? I am specifically required to insert a random character in the table after **2 seconds**

Comment: `for (int sleepinterruptus = 0; sleepinterruptus < 100; sleepinterruptus++) { if (kbhit()) extrawork(); sleep(20); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not call either MS `Sleep()` or gcc `sleep()` but go for a non-blocking function, as you have with MS `kbhit()`.

For a 1 second timer an example use is

```
clock_t target = clock() + CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
while(!kbhit() && clock() < target) {
    // some code if needed
}
```

The loop will end when a key is pressed, or after 1 second. You can check `kbhit()` again to find out which.

Comment: There is the possibility that the counter returned by `clock()` wraps, if you leave the program running for a very long time. In Windows `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is `1000` so that will wrap on the 49th day.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the `sleep` function is *not* part of the C11 standard. You could check by reading [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), the draft C11 standard. See also this [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website.

But `sleep` is part of POSIX. Read for example [sleep(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html).

You could want to use some [event looping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) library, such as [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) from GTK (cross-platform on Windows, Linux, MacOSX), or [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) or [libevent](https://libevent.org/).

You could want to use a terminal interface library, such as [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

You could consider writing a graphical application above cross-platform libraries such as [GTK](https://gtk.org/) (or [Qt](https://qt.io/), or [FLTK](https://www.fltk.org/); both requiring learning [programming in C++](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html))

You could decide to code a Windows-specific C program.

### Be sure to then read the documentation of the [WinAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API), e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/)

I never coded on Windows myself, but I believe you could be interested in the Windows specific [`Sleep` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep).

I guess that for a game, you need some input-multiplexing function. On Linux, [select(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) or [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) comes to mind. Perhaps you might be interested by [Socket.Poll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.poll?view=net-5.0) on Windows (but polling the keyboard or the mouse should be done otherwise).

#### For a game, I would recommend using [libSFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/).

Whatever API or library you would use, be sure to **read its documentation**.

Look also for *existing* open-source examples on [github](https://github.com/).

Read also the documentation of your C compiler (perhaps [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)) and of your debugger (maybe [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)). Enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler (with GCC, compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Consider using static analysis tools like [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/). Read perhaps [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report, and look (at end of 2020) into the [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) European project, and recent papers to [ACM SIGPLAN](http://www.sigplan.org/) sponsored conferences (about compilers and static analysis).

Be aware that PC keyboards have various layouts (mine is [AZERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY)). You may want to use some library abstracting these.

Comment: Oh yeah, I meant Sleep(). I don't mean something too sophisticated, just a console mini-game. As I mentioned, I'm still an amateur

Comment: This is the most elaborate and argued answer I received even though I was just looking for a simple idea. Much obliged for your efforts and tips! Extremely well done, but what WeatherVane mentioned above helped me more, specifically for the case I was looking into, whilst yours gave me more insight on the general idea.